# fullcalendar: can't view, the page is empty

Tags: php, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I did everything said in the [Basic Usage page](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/) and added the CDNs accordingly, but I cannot even see the basic display.
I tried a jsFiddle example too.
I'm very new to this.

```
<html>

    <head>
                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.min.css">
                 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
                 <script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/locales.min.js"></script>
                 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

                  <link rel="stylesheet" href="         https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.print.css">                                                                      

    </head>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

             $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
             // put your options and callbacks here
             })
        });   

    </script>

    <body>        
      <div id="calendar"></div>                                
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: put your JS fiddle example

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AzmJv/947/

Comment: You should paste your code here, in your question

Comment: your jsfiddle works fine for me and I can see and use the calendar. Besides, can you share your complete HTML markup and confirm if jQuery is loaded? can you see anything in the browser console?

Comment: i cant see anything in the browser console :( i put the HTML code there. also included <div id='calendar'></div>

Comment: second software guy. the calendar loads perfectly

Comment: what could be the mistake i made? does this code itself work for u?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<html>

    <head>
                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.min.css">
                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="         https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.print.css">       

                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>  
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>                                                                 
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                            // put your options and callbacks here
                        });
                    });   

                </script>
    </head>



    <body>        
      <div id="calendar"></div>        

    </body>
</html>
```

1) Always put your script inside your body or head.
2) Your issue was that you never imported moment.js. Your code gets locale.js, which is not needed to run this.
3) Also, please do check your browser console. You would have seen the issue that its not able to find moment.js.
Hope this helps!!

Comment: is it necessary to put script inside body/head? i normally keep my javascript in separate file and have it linked at the end of the body.

Comment: Correct. So your link is still inside your body tag. My point is, it should either be a child of the head tag or the body tag, whether its a script or a link to a file

Comment: thank you so much! it worked this time! iv lot to learn, just started learning on this :)

Comment: you will with time! just keep practising :)